# How to add a configuration file to a AWS application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been looking into how to route HTTP traffic to https for my Elastic Beanstalk environment. [AWS has documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html) on this that recommends using configuration files. I'm just not sure where I should paste this configuration? I'm quite now to AWS, so I'm love some newbie friendly advice.

I'm using an Application Load Balancer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in the docs cited,  `alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config` and `alb-http-to-https-redirection.config` are to be placed (after your modifications if needed; HTTPs requires SSL certificate) in your [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) folder.

So in your zip package  would have files `.ebextensions/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config` and/or `alb-http-to-https-redirection.config` along side your application.